# I want to update a pandas dataframe iteratively

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I need to check some conditions in 2 other columns and update another column iteratively. Basically I want to replace NaNs in smoking_status column with new categories.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df['age'][i] < 15 and df['smoking_status'][i] == np.nan:
        df['smoking_status'][i] = 'never smoked'
    elif df['age'][i] >= 15 and df['smoking_status'][i] == np.nan:        
        df['smoking_status'][i] = 'occassional smoker'
```

The code runs but when I check my updated table I still notice no change. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you share a testable dataframe fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use pandas' vectorized functions instead of looping through every problem. They are both faster and result in neater code:

```
cond = df['smoking_status'].isna()
df.loc[cond, 'smoking_status'] = np.where(df.loc[cond, 'Age'] < 15, 'never smoked', 'occassional smoker')
```